# Python package, python absolute path, Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sounds'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a Python package and some submodules just like [Python modules docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). There are my files and folders.

```
sounds/
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── formaters
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── items.py
```

```
# sounds/formaters/items.py

format_list = ['svg','png','jpg'\]
```

```
# sounds/main.py

from sounds.formaters import items
print(items.format_list)
```

then I run the below command.

```
python3 main.py

# and I tested

python3 sounds/main.py
```

But I got the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/sounds/main.py", line 1, in \<module\>
from sounds.formaters import items
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sounds'
```

what is wrong with my structres and codes? Where did I made a mistake? I have studied lots of blogs about python packages, modules and imports. All them impelemented same structure.

Comment: Hi, replace `from sounds.formaters import items` with `from .formaters import items` and run your `main.py` file, hopefully it will run.

Comment: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` would be the next error. It should just be ` from formaters import items` and everything will just work.

Comment: Thanks, @AbdullahMughal. I know relative import will run without error, but I would like to learn the absolute path and have deep knowledge about how it works. If you look at the Python module docs (section 6.4: packages), It uses an absolute path, and I would like to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, @BoyNandi. Yes maybe it works, But as I mentioned Python module docs section 6.4 (packages) uses an absolute path and starts from `sounds`. I used the same structure but why did I encounter the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to access **sounds** directory from inside the **sounds** direcotry notice that the `main.py` is inside the sounds directory so simply replace

```
# sounds/main.py

from sounds.formaters import items
print(items.format_list)
```

with

```
# sounds/main.py

from formaters import items
print(items.format_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, It works. I have already tested it. But there are some questions. How does Django set the root of projects and uses absolute paths for its imports? How can we create packages (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and use absolute imports from the root of projects like Django? I have used the same structure as Python docs, but I have encountered errors